# Detecting mobile phone in airplane mode

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, radiation, electrically-conductive

I am working on a project to detect mobile phones in a room to avoid cheating. But the airplane mode ha posed a problem. A google search told that all radiations are switched off during airplane mode. How can i detect mobile phone in airplane mode? Is there any way out? Even the faintest idea will help.

Comment: How can people cheat in airplane mode?

Comment: @Andyaka I assume the same way they'd cheat with a piece of paper.

Comment: Cheating not only in exams, but also in sports like chess where engines can be operated in airplane mode. And even in exams pdf files can be loaded in the phone.

Comment: All this kinda depends on how close I'm allowed to get to the test subject, and with what, for how long. A metal detector will almost certainly work - so what's your design criteria?

Comment: Ya Sean, actually we had thought of the metal detector approach, but it seems that the wearables like belts, and necklaces and also some religious belongings like kirpaan and kada(worn as wrist band) would interfere too much.

Comment: Then you are between technology and protocol. The real world solution to this problem right now is a pat down and over-the shoulder supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, you can't. Any operating piece of electronics will emit EMI, which you might be able to detect with a sufficiently sensitive antennae, but the amplitude is low by design, and likely to be swamped by other sources of EMI in the area. You'll also detect many other electronic devices, like pacemakers and digital watches.

All of which is moot, of course, if the person simply turns their phone *off*.